# Symfony throwing an error saying file is missing when it isn't

Tags: symfony

I am trying to recreate a copy of our live system on a local VM and am running into issues.

I have copied all the code from live to the local machine and then changed the following line in /var/www/trunk/web/app.php from prod to dev:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

If I go to the url I get the following but file /var/www/trunk/app/config/config_dev.yml definitely exists.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The file "/var/www/trunk/app/config/config_dev.yml" does not exist.' in /var/www/trunk/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/FileLocator.php:48 Stack trace: #0 
/var/www/trunk/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Config/FileLocator.php(54): Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator->locate('/var/www/trunk/...', NULL, true) #1
 /var/www/trunk/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php(42): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Config\FileLocator->locate('/var/www/trunk/...') #2
 /var/www/trunk/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/DelegatingLoader.php(52): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->load('/var/www/trunk/...', NULL) #3
/var/www/trunk/app/AppKernel.php(48): Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\DelegatingLoader->load('/var/www/trunk/...') 
#4 /var/www/trunk/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2409): AppKernel->registerContainerConfiguration(Object(Symfony in /var/www/trunk/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/FileLocator.php on line 48
```

If I change back from dev to prod in app.php it tells me that /var/www/trunk/app/config/config_prod.yml doesn't exists (but it does!)

I'm not quite sure where to look next. I'm more used to files actually being missing when the error says that they are!

Comment: If you're positive that files exist, this smells like a lack of permissions. Did you check those?

Comment: Start with clearing your cache. Blow away everything under app/cache/dev and app/cache/prod

Comment: Also you shouldn't need to change that AppKernel instantiation. If you're accessing app.php then you're accessing prod. If you're accessing app_dev.php, then you're accessing the dev environment. I'd worry more about getting dev to work first, then worry about prod.

Comment: Ok so clearing the cache doesn't make any difference. @jovan there are a lot of files so which ones were you thinking of and what permissions?

Comment: @williamsdb: Particullary those file within `/app`. I suggest you download a fresh copy of Symfony2 and compare if permissions of each files

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution turned out to be simple. Just needed to add the following to /etc/php.ini:

date.timezone = "Europe/London"

and the problems magically disappeared. No idea why but I am happy that it is resolved.